# Python-Eve: Use Pre-Request Event Hooks to modify data before inserting to DB

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I am adding new data into my Database by doing a POST-request on my eve-API.
Since there need to be added some data from the Python side I thought I could add these data by using a [pre-request event hook](http://python-eve.org/features.html#pre-request-event-hooks).

So is there a way to modify the data contained in the POST-request using a pre-request hook before inserting the data into the database? I already understood how to implement such a hook but do not have any clue about how to modify data before inserting to DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to look at [database hooks](http://python-eve.org/features#database-event-hooks), specifically at [insert hooks](http://python-eve.org/features#insert-events):

> When a POST requests hits the API and new items are about to be stored in the database, these vents are fired:
>
> `on_insert` for every resource endpoint.
>
> `on_insert_<resource_name>` for the specific  resource endpoint.
>
> **Callback functions could hook into these events to arbitrarily add new fields or edit existing ones.**

In the code below:

```
def before_insert(resource_name, documents):
    if resource_name == 'myresource':
        for document in documents:
            document['field'] = 'value'

app = Eve()
app.on_insert += before_insert

app.run()
```

Every time a POST hits the API the `before_insert` function is invoked. The function updates `field1` for every document. Since this callback  is invoked before the payload is sent to the database, changes will be persisted to the database.

An interesting alternative would be:

```
def before_insert(resource_name, documents):
    for document in documents:
        document['field'] = 'value'

app = Eve()
app.on_insert_myresource += before_insert

app.run()
```

In the callback we are not testing the endpoint name anymore. This is because we hooked our callback to the `on_insert_myresoure` event so the function will only be called when POST request are performed on the `myresource` endpoint. Better separation of concerns, code is simpler and also, improved performance since the callback is not going to be hit an *all* API inserts. Side note, eventually you can hook multiple callbacks to the same event (hence the use of the addition operator `+=`).

Comment: It looks like this hook is invoked after the validation progress. So is there a way to combine this with the validation since required fields are still raising `required_field` errors?

Comment: If the fields are required and they are missing validation kicks in and document is rejected. The hook fire before insertion and after validation. Can't you simply make the fields not-required? Or, you could customise the validator to process the `required` rule differently or, better, add support for a different rule (look at "Custom Validation" in the docs).

Comment: DB hooks on_fetch_item does not work with WSGI. When I run the server with ```python server.py``` Hooks work but when run the app with WSGI hooks dont work and no errors show in console.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to duplicate documents if a given property is in data.

I have to use pre_POST event hook to do that.

```
def pre_notifications(request):
    data = json.loads(request.get_data())
    if 'payload' in data and 'condition' in data:
        notification = data['payload']
        documents = []
        users = app.data.pymongo().db.users.find()
        for user in users:
            copy_notification = copy(notification)
            copy_notification['user_email'] = user['user_email']
            documents.append(copy_notification)
        request._cached_data = json.dumps(documents).encode('utf-8')
```

First, I tried to replace request.data but it does not work. Doing some search on code I figured out the _cached_data property. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the answer of @Gustavo (I cannot leave a comment in his answer). You can update the `request._cached_json` property without serializing your data.

Using his example:

```
def pre_notifications(request):
    data = json.loads(request.get_data())
    if 'payload' in data and 'condition' in data:
        notification = data['payload']
        documents = []
        users = app.data.pymongo().db.users.find()
        for user in users:
            copy_notification = copy(notification)
            copy_notification['user_email'] = user['user_email']
            documents.append(copy_notification)
        request._cached_json = documents
```